# Coding: changing a and b values

Tags: c#

Given `a = 6, b = 13` ,(for example) 
How to change `b = 6. a = 13` without third integer?

I need an algorithm or code.
There are many ways to do that , but i need the shortest one.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service We try to fix your code, we do not write your code –

Comment: @R0xx0rZzz you asked for the shortest one - in which way "shortest"? runtime / code?

Comment: @fubo shortest code i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, You can do the same in a verity of operations combinations, Let `aValue, bValue` be the two values then you can use following ways to perform swapping:

**Using + and -**

```
 aValue = aValue + bValue;  
 bValue = aValue - bValue;  
 aValue = aValue - bValue;
```

**Using * and /**

```
 aValue = aValue * bValue;  
 bValue = aValue / bValue;  
 aValue = aValue / bValue;
```

Using ^

```
 aValue = aValue ^ bValue;  
 bValue = aValue ^ bValue;  
 aValue = aValue ^ bValue;
```

Checkout the [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMXH09) for running example

Answer (score 3):

I think this is shortest

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the shortest

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref a, b, b = a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep in mind that this swap only works in case `a + b <= int.Max` so in productive I would always work with a temporary variable.

```
int a = 6, b = 13;
a = b + (b = a) - b;
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uNsA5n

---

This would work aswell but there is no measureable difference in performance.

```
a = b ^ (b = a) ^ b;
```